# Comparison and join of two different data frames with strings?

Tags: python, string, join, pandas, comparison

I would like to compare and then join two data frames with strings based on a common sequence within the strings.

Data looks like:

*data1:*

```
Kansas
Sacramento
Miami
Toronto
```

*data2*

```
Kansas_county
Sacramento_county
Miami_county
Vegas_county
```

desired result is:

```
col_data1            col_data2
Kansas               Kansas_county   
Sacramento           Sacramento_county
Miami                Miami_county
Toronto              N/A
N/A                  Vegas_county
```

The question is:

- How can I search for the common string in both source data sets?
- How can I take the contents of data1 and then select the corresponding row of data2 that contains the string?
- How can these then be joined?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Roman's answer, you can define a function to format one of your data columns, e.g.

```
In [105]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col':['Kansas', 'Sacramento', 'Miami', 'Toronto']})
In [106]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col':['Kansas_county', 'Sacramento_county', 'Miami_county', 'Vegas_county']})

In [107]: def f(x,delm='_'):
     ...      return x.split(delm)[0]

In [108]: df2['map_index'] = df2.col.map(lambda x: f(x))
In [109]: df2
Out[109]: 
                 col   map_index
0      Kansas_county      Kansas
1  Sacramento_county  Sacramento
2       Miami_county       Miami
3       Vegas_county       Vegas

In [110]: dfN = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on='col', right_on='map_index')

In [111]: dfN
Out[111]: 
        col_x              col_y   map_index
0      Kansas      Kansas_county      Kansas
1  Sacramento  Sacramento_county  Sacramento
2       Miami       Miami_county       Miami
3     Toronto                NaN         NaN
4         NaN       Vegas_county       Vegas
```

This does essentially the same thing that Roman outlined, but gives you a more general formatting capability (via whatever you want to put in your function, which can include regex parsing, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can add new column to first DataFrame and then use [pandas.merge()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html):

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col':['Kansas', 'Sacramento', 'Miami', 'Toronto']})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col':['Kansas_county', 'Sacramento_county', 'Miami_county', 'Vegas_county']})
>>>
>>> df1['county'] = df1['col'] + '_county'
>>>
>>> dfN = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_on='county', right_on='col', suffixes=['_data1', '_data2'])
>>>
>>> del dfN['county']
>>> dfN
    col_data1          col_data2
0      Kansas      Kansas_county
1  Sacramento  Sacramento_county
2       Miami       Miami_county
3     Toronto                NaN
4         NaN       Vegas_county
```